# series of errors in upgrading drupal from 7.21 to 7.23

Tags: drupal-7, undefined-index

I'm getting a whole host of error messages since upgrading the core code:
this message appears regularly:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in _ctools_list_themes() (line 567 of /home/xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/plugins.inc).
```

and when going to admin pages I'm greeted with this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 146 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 165 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_menu() (line 647 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in _ctools_list_themes() (line 567 of /home/xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/plugins.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 146 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in block_menu() (line 165 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_menu() (line 647 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.module).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_theme_default() (line 378 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in _update_process_info_list() (line 205 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/update/update.compare.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_sort_modules_by_info_name() (line 949 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_sort_modules_by_info_name() (line 949 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_sort_modules_by_info_name() (line 949 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Warning: uasort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function in system_themes_page() (line 139 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_themes_page() (line 148 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_themes_page() (line 166 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_themes_page() (line 167 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in system_themes_page() (line 190 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: name in theme_system_themes_page() (line 2739 of /home/xxx/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
```

I also cannot access the admin/config path or run update.php

I've tried doing a registry rebuild. that didn't seem to be the problem.

Everything is backed up & I have created a sql dump. Should I just completely wipe out the drupal site and reinstall? or is there an obvious patch to apply? it looks like the problem is in the modules part of the core code.

thanks.

Comment: Please use code instead of bold.

Answer (score 0):

How do you proceed when upgrading your core installation? Since all the errors seem to point to the Core install, it's unlikely ( although possible ) that the errors would actually be with Core itself.

I've done a few upgrades to 7.23 recently and all went fine. My preferred method is to use GIT, drush  & rsync. 
1/ Commit the latest state before upgrading
2/ Download last version in a separate folder
3/ Remove .git folder from downloaded version
4/ rsync latest version

It usually takes less than a few minutes.

```
1/ // Within my current install. let's call it /dev...
   git add .
   git commit -m "Drupal 7.21 before upgrade to 7.23"

2/ // Outside current install
   drush dl drupal //downloads the latest version

3/   rm -r drupal-7.23/.git* // removes all git info

4/ rsync -avz drupal-7.23/ dev //rsync versions
```

Comment: ah, perhaps it would help if I saved a commit to GIT. also, I never knew about rsync or that I was supposed to remove the git info from the download. do you think that would make any difference now? I'm hesitant to upgrade any of my other sites.

Comment: I've been researching rsync. this may be helpful to others: http://www.dave-cohen.com/node/1000005

Comment: & thank you, PatrickS. though I'm still sorting through the manpages on rsync, I at least have some direction!

Comment: If you don't remove the git folder from the Core version, it will replace your own dev version, therefore erasing all your commits!

Comment: This might be an ever better synopsis of the steps to using drush and rsync to update drupal core: http://thatsmytwocents.com/drupal-core-updates-drush-and-rsync

Comment: Happy to put you on the right track :) I used to dread core updates, with this method upgrades are painless. Upgrading modules using Drush is also very easy!